# lilypond: How to display changed chord names only?

Tags: lilypond

In German songbooks chordnames are only displayed if they have changed. Lilypond shows chordnames at the beginning of a new line even if the chordname has not changed. Is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: I didn't get the problem you're facing. I constructed a MWE [here](http://lilybin.com/90wz55/1) and the chord names are only displayed when there's a change. Anyway, I suspect the solution has to do with the `break-visibility` property.

Answer (score 1):

I just have finished my document by typesetting using "lualatex". Up to now I did not find another solution to my problem by hiding some chords manually by using \once \override ChordNames.ChordName.color = #white.

Hope to find another solution, soon.

Comment: You can use `\omit ChordName` instead of that override (at least in 2.19).  But you're right, the default behavior for `\set chordChanges = ##t` is to repeat the chord at the beginning of a new line.